# Creating a new xcode project with single page application while Appdelegate file

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I create the new project with single page application while create the new project but their is no problem But following things i can't understand,

1)When create the project and that appdelegate file name usaually project name then"Appdelegate.h" and project name then"Appdelegate.m" but in my situation their is only "Appdelegate.h" and "Appdelegate.m"

2)how to change the when the project is created that time Appdelegate name is application name then after "Appdelegate.h" and application name then after "Appdelegate.m"

like my project name is "TestApplciation"

then creates the AppDelegate file name is
TestApplciationAppDelegate.h
TestApplciationAppDelegate.m

but it is not a usally create in my case then how to creates like wise.

[image]

Thanx in advance for helping me.
iPhone Tec

Comment: Please do not create irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no technical difference between `AppDelegate` and `TestApplicationAppDelegate`. There is not any reason to change it. Apple decided with the new version of Xcode that they would no longer use the old naming convention of AppDelegate because it's messy.

If you really want to for some reason, you can open AppDelegate.h and right click on `AppDelegate` right after `@interface` and select Refactor->Rename.

Comment: Thanks for spend your valuable time and share your valuable knowledge.